# jQuery's .on('click') not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Templating is done in Jade, `#name` is putting a ID on the tag and `.name` puts a class

```
      div#chatroom
        div.row#chatcontainer.chatbg
          div.large-12.columns
            div.row
              div.large-10.columns
                h2#chatanchor.thin Party
                  i.fa.fa-minus-square-o
              div.large-2.columns
                i.fa.fa-users

            div.row.chatbox
              div.large-12.columns.chatwindow
                div.mymessage 
                    p Bill: Templating!
                div.theirmessage
                    p.theirmessage Fredrickson: Templating!


              div.row
                div.large-12.columns.sitbottom
                  div.row.collapse
                    div.small-10.columns.large-10.sitbottom
                      input(type="text").sitbottom
                    div.small-2.columns.large-2.sitbottom
                      button(type="submit", class="button postfix sitbottom") Send
```

I have a simple chat window and when I click the h2 at the top it is supposed to minimize using this:

```
 $('#chatanchor').on('click', function(e) {
    console.log("Here");
  });
```

The bind is called within `document.ready` in `jQuery` but doesn't work when I click it, but if I copy the code and paste it into the dev console and then click it, it works, so I'm not sure why it is not binding on page load.

Comment: Made a quick pen everything works as it should, are you sure your javascript code is running with no errors and is running with `document.ready` or included before the closing body tag? [example](http://codepen.io/Ayeetu/pen/meKNzp?editors=101)

Answer (score 3):

It would seem that the element is being added after the DOM is ready, so your event isn't getting attached. Have it attach to any new elements that match your selector with the following:

```
$(document).on('click', '#chatanchor', function(e) {
     console.log("Here");
});
```

Comment: No such luck unfortunately.

Comment: This is exactly what you'll need.

Comment: Are there any JavaScript errors in the console? If this doesn't work, you'll need to provide more info.

Comment: Huh... Weird... I use [Cloud9](https://c9.io/) as my IDE (because I absolutely love it) and some how it must have lost its connection with the file I was working in because when I was saving it wasn't actually saving, I refreshed the page and noticed the bind was gone and when I put it back and saved, it worked... Using what I had originally had.. So I'm just going to delete this question but just so you know

Comment: Won't let me delete because there is an answer.

Comment: Then write your solution briefly as an answer and mark it accepted for the sake of other people who have the same problem. It seems a general problem for your platform and I'm sure there are some others who are looking for this answer.